# Overriding node draw style inherited from every node style messes up positioning

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes

I have been trying to draw a tree with TikZ. All nodes should be circles, so I use the `every node` style. There are some additional labels on some nodes, which have to be exceptions. I have tried this:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,circle}]
    \node {A}
      child { node (b) {B} }
      child { node {C} };
    \node[draw=none,below=1mm of b] {hint};  
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But the hint is too far away from `B`:

[image: failing example]

When I remove the `every node` style, the positioning is correct:

[image: fixed positioning, wrong style]

How can I fix this?

Comment: This problem cost me quite some time when it occurred, so I thought I'd put it up in the spirit of [Encyclopedia Stack Exchange](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/). Maybe there are better solutions than mine.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Aside from the fact that I should probably not have used `every node` for this purpose, the underlying problem is simple, but somewhat hidden in the documentation (according to my limited efforts).

`draw=none` turns off the drawing of the shape but does not do away with the shape itself! Therefore, the hint node keeps the `circle` shape from `every node` which causes the positioning:

[image: failing example with helper line]

There does not seem to be a `null`-shape. The standard shape is `rectangle`, so resetting to this

```
\node[draw=none,rectangle,below=1mm of b] {some hint for B};
```

provides the desired result:

[image: fixed]

Comment: another solution, is to put the `[every node...]` on the first node creating the diagram: `\node[every node/.style={draw,circle}] {A} ...` or one could use scopes, etc. There are many possibilities. :) Maybe you could add them?

Comment: By the way, your remark about a null-shape gave me this idea, which can be useful sometimes: `\tikzset{no shape/.style = {rectangle, inner sep=0pt, draw=none, fill=none }}`

Comment: @zeroth That's probably a better way to perform the original task, but does not relate to the "positioning problem" which I wanted to address here.

Comment: @JLDiaz You will also need to re-set `minimum size` and what not …

Answer (score 7):

[Raphael’s own answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101006/16595) is of course correct: 
The hint node inherits the `every node` styles.

If you only want to change the tree’s nodes, you can set the `every node` style locally to the tree if you use

```
\path[options] node {parent node} child …
```

instead.

While the `positioning` is great, a simple hint like that can be placed with the help of the `label` options. There is no need to name the node `(b)` anymore and one can easily change the text without researching which hint belongs to which node.

Note that I have used `.append style` handler, especially for the `every label` style.
When a label (which is just a node, too) is placed it inherits also the `every node` style, but the `every label` style overwrites any possible settings.

This can be seen if you use the `every label/.style` instead of `.append style`. Suddenly the shape’s border is visible because the `.style` handler overwrites an already existing `draw=none` in the `every label` style.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[every node/.append style={draw,circle}] node {A}
    child { node (b) {B} }
    child { node {C} };
  \node[draw=none,below=1mm of b] {some hint for B};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every label/.append style={shape=rectangle},% these three options could have
  label distance=1mm,                         % been assigned to a \path
  every node/.append style={draw,circle},     % like in the example above.
]
  \node {A}
    child { node[label=below:some hint for B] {B} }
    child { node {C} };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: This is probably a better way to code the thing, circumventing the problem I have addressed.