# Reduce white space above TikZ label

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, labels

I'm new to TikZ, and have drawn the following picture,

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,arrows}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,shape=circle,inner sep=2pt,fill=black}]
    \node [label=above:$a$]{}
        child {node[label=above:$b$,label=below:$p\land q$]{}}
        child {node[label=above:$c$,label=below:$p\land \lnot q$]{}}
;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But there's too much space above the propositional formula on the right, is there any way I can decrease the amount of whitespace to be closer to the amount of whitespace for the labels a, b, c?

[edit] Jesse linked me to a way of adjusting the position of the label manually, but a way to align both labels without fine tuning would be nice.

Comment: Does this help http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57484/34618?

Comment: That question is about how to remove whitespace around the picture, while I'm trying to remove it above the label. I'm not sure how they are related.

Comment: Could you please check this http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58878/34618 again?

Comment: Thanks, that one works, but a way to align the labels without fine tuning would be nice.

Comment: After writing my answer I've found that [Overriding node draw style inherited from every node style messes up positioning](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/101005/1952) solves a similar problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This bad aligning comes from `every node/.style={draw,shape=circle,inner sep=2pt,fill=black}`. Labels are also nodes so `shape=circle` makes all labels being circles.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,arrows}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,shape=circle,inner sep=2pt,fill=black},
                    every label/.style={draw,fill=none}]
    \node [label=above:$a$]{}
        child {node[label=above:$b$,label=below:$p\land q$]{}}
        child {node[label=above:$c$,label=below:$p\land \lnot q$]{}}
;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can change this behavior with `every label/.style={shape=rectangle, draw=none, fill=none}` or `every label/.append style={shape=rectangle}` which produces

[image]

If you want to understand why options `draw=none` and `fill=none` are included in `every label` definition, look at [Every non-label node in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49096/1952).